# Display content using javascript's onkeyup event on condition

Tags: javascript

I have a form,

When a user types a value in the field below called advance,

```
<div class="form-group">
     {{ Form::label('advance', 'Advance') }}
     {{ Form::text('advance', 0 , array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'txt6', 'onkeyup'=>'displayDate()')) }}
</div>
```

the date automatically displays in the date field below of the form,

```
<div class="form-group">
     {{ Form::label('date', 'Advance issued on') }}
     {{ Form::text('date', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'date')) }}
</div>
```

This is happening because I am using javascript's on keyup event.

I would like the date to only display if the value entered in the
advance field is more than one. i.e if user keys in zero,
the date does not show. How can I achieve this?

This is my javascript :

```
function displayDate() {
    var x = document.getElementById("txt6");
    document.getElementById('date').value = Date();
}
```

Comment: You can just validate the value entered in the advance field inside the `displayDate` function by using an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.value` can also be used to retrieve the value, as well as set it. So instead of getting the element and assigning it to `x`, assign the elements **value**, then if the value is greater than `1` do the thing...

```
var x = document.getElementById("txt6").value;

if (x > 1) {
    document.getElementById('date').value = Date();   
}
```